# Picture viewer that displays EXIF and allows to delete photos

Tags: photo-viewer

I am learning photography with DSLR. Generally, at this early stage, I am taking several photos of the same subject with different camera settings. While I view those pictures on my PC, I find one to be superior to others. Now, in an outdoor shoot, I have bunch of such pictures of different subjects. It has become hectic for me to choose the best picture from the heap, note it down, locate the junk ones in the file system and delete those. Hence, I wish to see a picture viewer that

- Of course, displays a picture
- Shows EXIF data in a side-pane
- Allows deletion of unneeded photos from within the viewer itself

Can anybody please suggest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, you can use [PMView Pro](http://www.pmview.com). It will show EXIF information in the Information panel. Once you open that panel, it sill stay open. Use PgUp and PgDown to navigate between images and press DEL to delete. It's that simple!

For Linux, try [Geeqie](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net). It works similarly and is quick too. They have a simple overlay which shows basic EXIF information which stays visible as you switch files. Pressing DEL also deletes images. When you want to see the full EXIF data, you have to open a popup.

Those are the two ones I use because they are so fast but that functionality is available elsewhere too. The main point with these is that you can go through images and delete them before importing them into Lightroom or other DAM Software which is slower and not really worth it for the images you delete.

Comment: You are the "**man**". Exactly serves my purpose.

Comment: Geeqie can also display more-than-basic EXIF info in a panel instead of an overlay, and is extremely configurable in terms of layout and behavior in general, and you can create "external editors" that can run any command you want on a displayed image via key bindings, which means it plays very nicely with exiftool, etc. if you want to extend its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom is the top dog for managing photos and it give you a full rating system with from 1 to 5, color code, flag rejected / preferred and add tags; and that's only in the organization part of Lightroom. Lightroom also has most of the common photo editing tools that you would use in Photoshop for editing your photos. I suggest downloading the 30 day trial and see how well you can organize your photos. Changes are that once your hooked, you will never look back.

a Free option that i see a lot of people using is Google Picasa but the only issue with that is if you are shooting RAW, you need to make sure that you have the Codec/Driver installed on the computer so that Picasa can read the RAW image.

But based on what you are looking for, Lightroom is your tool.

[Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html)

Comment: Does Lightroom allow me to delete photo from within the application itself?

Comment: Yes, when you hit the delete key, it gives you the option to delete from catalog or hard drive

Comment: Sorry, but I have to mention: Lightroom is the top SLOW dog for managing photos.

Comment: Lightroom is not slow. I find it to be quick.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a digital camera you are discovering it's kinda useless without good software.

Have you tried what was supplied with the camera? Most, if not all, will show exif.

You really need something like Lightroom if you intend to do much of this. Not only do programs like that show exif, but also IPTC, with keywords, titles, captions, etc, and allow filtering and  sorting by those criteria.

Some free alternatives are XNViewMP, Mylio, or Picasa. Or open source software like Darktable, RAWtherapee, etc.

Comment: I can't afford purchasing Lightroom at present. Haven't found it from some other source from the Internet so far.